# Android Parsing Xml Without Root Element

Tags: android

Hi I have to parse an XML file in android but there aren't root element in Xml. Like that below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iii>
    <kkk>test</kkk>
    <ppp>000</ppp>
</iii>

<iii>
    <kkk>test</kkk>
    <ppp>000</ppp>
</iii>

<iii>
    <kkk>test</kkk>
    <ppp>000</ppp>
</iii>
```

..

Is it possible to parse without root element ? Thank you.

Comment: No, because it is not (well-formed) XML.

Comment: This is not well-formed XML in the first place. All correct XML documents have exactly one root element. To parse this data, you'll have to either update the component that generates the data or build your own parser for what essentially is a custom data format that happens to look a lot like XML.

Comment: Now I think I have to write Json service. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is not valid XML, so no parser will accept this. If you can fix the generating part of the application, do that.

The simplest way to fix it if you cannot do anything about the document generator, is to give it a root element. Just put `<root>` just after the `<?xml>` and `</root>` at the end of the document. Then feed that to your XML parser.

Comment: The file updating continuous via php, maybe I can add root tags with php but how.. Thanks.

Comment: You could process the file before feeding it to the XML parser.

Comment: Which parser do you advice ? I use it. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on your application, and I haven't used any XML parser on Android before, so I wouldn't know. I reckon there is quite some info to be found online.